# black diamond question marks

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml, character-encoding

if you look on this page:
http://www.lyricsinger.org/lyric/michel-sardou/c-est-ma-vie

there are several black diamonds with question marks in them. these are french characters.

in the database, the TEXT field they are stored in is set to utf8_general_ci
in the header you can see i have made the utf-8 charset declaration

it makes no sense why it isn't showing the characters properly.

Comment: What do the characters look like if you do a SELECT * from the database and look at what's come back, that should tell you if they have got scrambled in the database or when they've been written out to the HTML. Consider using something the HTML markup codes like &eacute; for an accented e, to render the characters in HTML instead of writing out the literal character and relying on the encoding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important that you display the text with the same encoding as the source of the data. So for example, if you put the content in ISO-8859-1 (e.g in the admin part the encoding is ISO-8859-1, or the file you've loaded contains ISO-8859-1 content), it doesn't matter what the database collation is, the text will not be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The linked page is not Unicode (it claims to be utf-8), it's Latin-1 aka 8859-1. Decode your source texts properly before use.